# How to get the latest created contact based on the account

Tags: trigger

I've to get the latest created contact for each account and mark the field `Newest=true` on the selected contact record.

Suppose,
I've two account A & Account B;

Example 1:

> Account A had contact created on
>
> Contact 1 :  20/5/18(created date)
>
> Contact 2 :  21/5/18 (created date)
>
> Contact 3  : 25/5/18(created date)

So I've to get the contact 3 which is created on latest i.e 25/5/18. and mark the Newest=true.  And for contact 1 and contact 2 mark `newest = false`, if it true.

Example 2 :

Account B had contact created on

> Contact 6 :  20/5/18(created date)
>
> Contact 7 :  21/5/18 (created date)
>
> Contact 8  : 28/5/18(created date)
>
> Contact 9  : 28/5/18(created date)

So I've to get the contact 8 and 9, cause two contact created on latest date, and mark contact 8 and contact 9 to `newest = true` and contact 6,7 to `newest = false`.

I'm trying to achieve it by the different way like aggregate query and others, but not getting success. can you please help on this.

I'm not expecting any big code from the community, just expecting brief idea to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `CreatedDate` is not sufficient for finding the latest records.

> If you insert several records through a List all records will get
>   almost same Date and Time.

In that case applying `Order By Id` as well will give more accurate result.

```
[Select id, name, (Select id, name, createddate from Contacts order by createddate desc, Id desc ) from Account]
```

Comment: it gives us only one record as limit 1. but condition for 2nd example will not satisfied here.

Comment: Removed the Limit.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the soql to fetch the most recently created contact with Account:

```
Select id, name, (Select id, name, createddate from Contacts order by createddate desc limit 1) from Account limit 10
```

These can be fetched in a 
 `Map<Id, Account>` say accountMap and one can iterate over the map to get the associated Contacts:

```
for(Account acc :  accountMap.values()){
   List<Contacts> conlist = acc.Contacts;
   for(Contact c : conlist){
      //your code to update the newest = true;
   }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you proceed!

Comment: @amol Did the answer helped you? Upvote the answer if it was helpful to you so that this thread can be helpful to the others as well, in case they find themselves in the similar code scenario need.